# British Radio serial with a tyrannical computer looking after a teen boy and girl on a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, radio-play

I remember listening to this serial in the late 80's.  It was really well written.  At one point they come to a pyramid and have to enter it by solving problems.  I think this might have been a bbc serial, but i'm not sure

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/242583/book-about-ai-called-angels-who-look-after-a-child-left-alone-on-a-spaceship (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like *[Earthsearch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthsearch)* by James Follett, first broadcast on BBC Radio 4 in 1981/1982, but maybe repeated later.

There's a tiny group of young people on a spaceship, their lives run by computers:

> From infancy, the four third-generation crew members (now in their
>   early twenties) have been raised by robots and by the Angels –
>   mysterious unseen beings who run the ship and who only manifest as
>   disembodied voices. *[...]* the ruthless, manipulative control of the Challenger's megalomaniacal control computers, Angel One and Angel Two.

And there's a huge structure that they need to solve a puzzle to get into:

> The only sign of life is a huge ten-mile-high tower on the equator,
>   with a tiny village nearby. *[...]* The crew examine the tower, finding
>   that there is a door set into one side which cannot be opened. Peeron
>   says that many of his predecessors have made attempts over the
>   centuries – for example, by hitting the door with battering rams – but
>   it will not budge. It is said that it is held shut by a "lock of
>   knowledge". Darv eventually works out how to open the ingeniously
>   simple lock, which requires a low grade of technology which would only
>   be available to people who have already worked out basic principles of
>   science and engineering.

(Quotes from the Wikipedia article.)